# ASP.NET - VB.NET input into MS-ACCESS with autoincrement

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, ms-access, auto-increment

I have an ms-access database called db.mdb and it contains various table. I;m creating a Account Creation page with ASP.NET and VB.NET.

I'm trying to input fields within the page into ms-acess db but when I open the db there are no values entered despite web develop not showing any errors.

Can you kindly help me?

This is the code:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.Odbc



Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtName.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnCreateAccount_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCreateAccount.Click

        Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Brian\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite3\db.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;")

        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [USER] (UserName, UserSurname, Address, Country, TelNo, UserLogin, UserPassword, UserTypeID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", conn)




        If txtPass.Text = txtCPass.Text Then

            conn.Open()


            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = txtName.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserSurname", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = txtSurname.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = txtUsername.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Country", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = txtCountry.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TelNo", OleDbType.Integer).Value = txtTelNo.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserLogin", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = txtUsername.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserPassword", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = txtPass.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserTypeID", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = "U"





            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            conn.Close()
            lblAccount.Visible = True



        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

EDIT:

So I'm trying to autonumber the UserID field. It's set as auto number from the access database. Whenever I try to input the details into the page from the page, it won't allow me, giving me an error that the AutoNumber field cannot be NULL. So I added the piece of code :

```
newID = Int32.Parse(cmd2.ExecuteScalar()) + 1
```

So that I get the maximum number from that column in the table and increment it by 1 and then added with the other command.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = newID
```

However its giving me an error saying

```
Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't open the connection before calling **cmd2.ExecuteScalar()** function. And first parameter is wrong. Should be @UserID instead of @Address.

```
conn.Open()
newID = Int32.Parse(cmd2.ExecuteScalar()) + 1
'Not sure what is column type (Varchar or Int)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", OleDbType.Integer, 2).Value = newID
...
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()
```

Comment: ahh ok thanks. but now its giving me a new error in this line `Dim cmd2 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT MAX(UserID) FROM USER", conn)` saying theres an error in the 'FROM'

Comment: Try - SELECT MAX(UserID) FROM [USER]

Comment: Thanks.. every problem seems to be leading to another though. I updated the question with the new error

Comment: If UserID is autonumber in Column, should not be putting in Insert Statement. Access will set it to the next value by itself.

Comment: Ok so I removed that code and its giving me the usual error (Data type mismatch in criteria expression.) at the line cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: Did you removed BOTH in Insert Statement (INSERT INTO [USER] .. and Parameter?

Comment: Is it all your Access table columns are varchar datatype?

Comment: No, the UserID is Autonumber, TelNo and UserTypeID are NUmbers. Changed the original code because I forgot to change them and I still get the same error

Comment: Ohh sorry, the others are Text (which is VarChar as I presume)

Comment: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32. this is the new error sorry

Comment: You still missing to convert for TelNo at parameter. Convert.ToInt32(txtTelNo.Text)

Comment: Thanks I fixed it.. there was en error in the relationships in the db!